# Plot multiple ordered conditional box plots using columns from a data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, boxplot

I am trying to plot several ordered (ie., from high to low median) conditional box plots from a single data frame. The general sequence is as follows:

1. Reverse sort group medians for variable1 according to variable.group ;
2. Create ordered conditional box plot using variable.group and sorted medians;
3. Repeat (loop?) process for remaining variables in data frame.

I want to loop through about 70 variables using the above process but am stuck moving from `tapply` to `aggregate`, accessing each variable in the dataframe, and coding the looping sequence.  Apologies in advance for the lack of elegance in my R code below:

```
bpdf = data.frame(group=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
           x=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4),
           y=c(7,5,2,9,7,6,3,1,2),
           z=c(4,5,2,9,8,9,7,6,7))

sorted.medians = rev(sort(with(bpdf,tapply(bpdf$x,bpdf$group,median))))

boxplot(bpdf$x~factor(bpdf$group,levels=names(sorted.medians)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you need just to put your 2 lines within `lapply`:

```
lapply(bpdf[,-1],function(x){
     ## decreasing better than rev here
     y <- sort(tapply(x,bpdf$group,median),decreasing=TRUE)
     boxplot(x~factor(bpdf$group,levels=names(y)))
})
```

**EDIT** to plot variable name , you use `main` argument of the boxplot and you loop over the colanmes of `bpdf`:

```
lapply(colnames(bpdf[,-1]),function(i){
     ## decreasing better than rev here
     x <- bpdf[,i]
     title <- paste0('title',i) ## you can change it here
     y <- sort(tapply(x,bpdf$group,median),decreasing=TRUE)
     boxplot(x~factor(bpdf$group,levels=names(y)),main=title)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for both answers!  I'd upvote you both but can't since I'm a noob.

Comment: How can I add each variable name as the title to each plot?  The following adds all var names:       par(mfrow=c(1,3))
lapply(bpdf[-1],function(x){
  y <- sort(tapply(x,bpdf$group,median),decreasing=TRUE)
  boxplot(x~factor(bpdf$group,levels=names(y)),
          main=paste(names(bpdf[-1])))
})

Comment: @QuiGonJin, you are still encouraged to accept an answer by clicking the big tick mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, I think following should do what you want:

1. Load in a few packages and create some data:

   ```
   library(plyr)
   library(reshape2)
   dd = data.frame(group=c("A","B","C", "D"),
                 x1=runif(40),x2=runif(40),x3=runif(40),x4=runif(40))
   ```
2. Now calculate the median conditional on the variable and group

   ```
   dd_m = melt(dd, "group")
   meds = ddply(dd_m, c("variable", "group"), summarise, m = median(value))
   ```
3. Order the data frame by variable and median:

   ```
   sorted_meds = meds[with(meds, order(variable, -m)), ]
   ```
4. Look through the variables, and sort each data frame in turn:

   ```
   for(var in unique(sorted_meds$variable)){
     grp_order = sorted_meds[sorted_meds$variable==var, ]$group
     dd_tmp = dd_m[dd_m$variable==var,]  
     dd_tmp$group = factor(dd_tmp$group, levels = grp_order)
     boxplot(dd_tmp$value ~ dd_tmp$group)
   }
   ```